# What are these unnamed icons in my iPhone's internal storage?

Tags: windows-explorer, iphone

I was accessing the photos stored on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2 through my Windows 8.1 laptop just now when I noticed one of the few folders in the `iPhone...Internal Storage...DCIM` directory contained 4 unnamed hard drive icons without any details:

[image: iPhone Internal Storage folder view in explorer]

Upon investigation in the properties window the "files" are of type "Local Disk", sharing the same icon as my hard drives, and are each a little more than 1KB in size.

What are these strange files and what purpose do they serve?
Why are they without any details or properties?

---

**Update 1:** Continued research turned up additional threads from the apple forums:

[Windows explorer see's multiple "Local Disk" files in the iphone DCIM folders](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6585223)

[How to remove local disk files?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27943547#27943547)

The second one is the more useful one in that it says the cause is photos in the "recently deleted" folder. On my iPhone 4 with iOS 7 and no Photo Stream I don't see this folder. Can anyone who can confirm this idea?

---

**Update 2:** I tried to copy the file elsewhere because I was going to experiment and see if it was a JPG or PNG in disguise, but got this pop-up:

[image: Local Disk Copy Error]

Comment: It looks like Explorer (Windows) is simply not able to figure out what they are and is getting confused. Try viewing the same location via OS X and see what it shows.

Comment: Don't own a mac. Can anyone else try that?

Comment: Maybe someone will and let you know, but as for this question the answer would simply be to ignore those 'drives' in Windows. What they are is irrelevant from the point of view of actually using the device.

Comment: @Karan My point of view isn't just using the device - I'm curious as to what the files are. I think that's okay for this SE site but if it is off-topic let me know so I can migrate it/not do it again. All in all, though, "ignore them" is not the answer to "What are these strange files and what purpose do they serve?"

Comment: It's on-topic IMO but I would still advise you to delete and ask over at apple.SE instead. You're far more likely to get an answer there from all the Mac/iPhone experts. (Perhaps you can ask on Meta there first to see if they'll take it.)

Comment: @Karan The main issue here is Windows, though. So I'm pretty sure that Apple.SE wouldn't accept it.

Comment: I think the main issue is playing inside a hierarchy never designed to be exposed directly to the user.

Comment: @slhck: The main issue as I see it is the OP wanting to know what those files are. Just because he's seeing them on Windows because he doesn't own a Mac, and because Windows naturally misidentifies these files, is completely irrelevant. Like I said, the apple.SE guys should know what the files are and satisfy the OP's curiosity.